# How to import everything inside a folder into a single module in Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I simply want to take all my .py files from a single folder (I don't care about the sub-folders for now) and put them into a single module.

The use case I'm having here is that I'm writing some pretty standard object-oriented code and I'm using a single file for every class, and I don't want to have to write `from myClass import myClass` for every class into my `__init__.py`. I can't use Python3, so I'm still working with `imp`and `reload`and such.

At the moment I'm using

```
# this is __init__.py
import pkgutil
for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    if not is_pkg:
        __import__(__name__ + "." + name)
```

and it doesn't seem to work, it includes the packages but it includes them as modules, so that I have to write `MyClass.MyClass` for a class that is defined in a file with it's own name. That's silly and I don't like it.

I've been searching forever and I'm just getting more confused how complicated this seemingly standard use case seems to be. Do python devs just write everything into a single file? Or do they always have tons of `import`s?

Is this something that should be approached in an entirely different way?

Comment: Python devs don't have everything in one module, but not a module per class either, which would render modules a bit useless. Think of modules as units to bundle functions and classes which semantically belong together and of packages to do the same with modules + functions and classes in the `__init__.py` of the package. And the they have ”tons” ob imports. At least as much to see where which name comes from. Don't use * imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What you really want to do

To do the job you need to **bind** your class names to namespace of your `__init__.py` script.
After this step you will be able to just `from YourPackageName import *` and just use your classes directly. Like this:

```
import YourPackageName 
c = YourPackageName.MyClass()
```

or

```
from YourPackageName import *
c = MyClass()
```

---

## Ways to achieve this

You have multiple ways to import modules dynamically: `__import__()`, `__all__`.

But.

The only way to bind names into namespace of current module is to use `from myClass import myClass` statement. Static statement.

In other words, content of each of your `__init__.py` scripts should be looking like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

from .MySubPackage import * 
from .MyAnotherSubPackage import * 
from .my_pretty_class import myPrettyClass
from .my_another_class import myAnotherClass
...
```

And you should know that even for a dynamic `__all__`:

> It is up to the package author to keep this list up-to-date when a new version of the package is released.

(https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

---

## So a clear answers to your questions:

> Do python devs just write everything into a single file?

No, they don't.

> Or do they always have tons of imports?

Almost. But definitely not tons. You need to import each of your modules just once (into an appropriate `__init__.py` scripts). And then just import whole package or sub-package at once.

---

## Example

Let's assume that there is next package structure:

```
MyPackage
    |---MySubPackage
    |       |---__init__.py
    |       |---pretty_class_1.py
    |       |---pretty_class_2.py
    |---__init__.py
    |---sleepy_class_1.py
    |---sleepy_class_2.py
```

Content of the `MyPackage/MySubPackage/__init__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

from .pretty_class_1 import PrettyClass1
from .pretty_class_2 import PrettyClass2
```

Content of the `MyPackage/__init__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

from .MySubPackage import *
from .sleepy_class_1 import SleepyClass1
from .sleepy_class_2 import SleepyClass2
```

---

As result, now we are able to write next code in our application:

```
import MyPackage

p = MyPackage.PrettyClass1()
s = MyPackage.SleepyClass2()
```

or

```
from MyPackage import *

p = PrettyClass1()
s = SleepyClass2()
```

Comment: `from MyPackage import PrettyClass, SleepyClass` is another possibility. And `from … import *` is discouraged by the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) unless the module is designed for that.

Comment: @BlackJack Of course you are right, but your comment is relevant to importing some foreign packets. And we are talking about more difficult topic: about packet creation (about packet design) - not about importing foreign packets. As a result, your comment is too obvious. More over,  `__all__` (which I briefly mentioned earlier) is a one of the ways to design module to be properly imported by a `from … import *` construction.